# Transforming markdown files in folders into a documentation

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, file-system, markdown

I start coding a simple application: I transform markdown files in folders into documentation.

My architecture is very flat. My code looks like a series of unit function called one after the other.

```
def main():
    config = get_user_config(os.getcwd())
    sources_dir = config['sources_dir']
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(sources_dir):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.md'):
            markdown_file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            html_block = transform_html_into_markdown(markdown_file_path)

            wrapped_html = '{{% extends "base.html" %}}{{% block content %}}{0}{{% endblock %}}'.format(html_block)

            html = render_html(wrapped_html, config)

            html_file_path = get_html_file_path(markdown_file_path, sources_dir)

            write_html_file(html_file_path, html)
```

What I really like:

- I can unit test every function. Code is simple to understand, no fancy stuff.
- Each function is in its own module.

What I do not like:

- My `main()` method is growing until I create two functions to rule them all. I have the impression of hiding the dust under the carpet.
- If I want for instance increase the number of process doing some calculation, I will probably need some hard refactoring.
- Everything is synchronous.

Do you have some idea to improve my code? Should I try something else?

Comment: _"two functions to rule them all"_ - which is the second?

Comment: @Eric If my `main(){}` function become huge, I used to separate in two functions `main(){a(); b();}` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change - extract iteration logic to its own generator:

```
def markdown_files(config):
    sources_dir = config['sources_dir']
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(sources_dir):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.md'):
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)

def main():
    config = get_user_config(os.getcwd())
    for path in markdown_files(config):    
        html_block = transform_html_into_markdown(path)

        # ...
```

For one, this eliminates a level of nesting, which is always a good thing

Also you can add things like exclude paths to your config at a later date, without having to change your processing code. Note that this might require you to rethink passing sources_dir into `get_html_file_path`, as any filtering logic might end up duplicated...

---

Second change: wrap the entire processing routine in a single function:

```
def process_file(config, path):  
    html_block = transform_html_into_markdown(path)

    # ...


def main():
    config = get_user_config(os.getcwd())
    for md_path in markdown_files(config):
        process_file(config, md_path)
```

So that later you can parallelize it, if you really need to:

```
import multiprocessing
import functools  # we can't directly pass a lambda into map

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(
    functools.partial(process_file, config=config),
    markdown_files(config)
)
```

Comment: nice answer, thank you. So I should only make my code more "functionnal" ?